# Recursion or Not Recursion

Tags: recursion

I have a function A that invokes function B. In turn function B invokes function A. This continues till a particular condition is met in Function A or Function B. Is this recursion or not? Please help me arrive at a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is

> the process of defining a function or calculating a number by the repeated application of an algorithm

So if your process repeats the pattern of function A -> function B ->  funciton A -> function B ..., it's recursion

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about mutual recursion. 
Check this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion